# format or manipulate date from server in client-side

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript date properties on the serverside called startDate and endDate, and I inject this into an html page using a templating engine (ejs).

```
<main>
        <% if (events.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="grid">
            <% for (let i=0; i<events.length; i++) { %>
            <article class="card">
                <div class="card__text">
                    <h1>
                        <%= events[i].title %>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card__img">
                    <img src="<%= events[i].imageUrl %>" alt="<%= events[i].title %>">
                </div>
                <div class="card__text card__description">
                    <p>
                        <%= events[i].description %>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__text">
                    <p>
                        Start Time:
                        <%= events[i].startDate%>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__text">
                    <p>
                        End Date:
                        <%= events[i].endDate %>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__text">
                    <p>
                        <%= events[i].location %>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card__text">
                    <h2>$
                        <%= events[i].price %>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card__actions">
                    <a href="/events/<%= events[i]._id %>" class="btn">
                        Details
                    </a>
                    <%- include('../includes/add-to-calendar.ejs', {event:events[i]}) %>
                </div>
            </article>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <% } else { %>
        <h1>No Events Found!</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>
```

Where the startDate and endDate are javascript dates. Before I was formatting them and putting them into a separate array but my datastructure is to complicated now to continue this approach... Is there a way to format this date on the client side? I can think of ways but they seem a bit convoluted. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not call a function to format the date? `<%= formatDate(events[i].startDate) ; %>` ?

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work, just declare the function it in ejs brackets <% %>... what would be good if I could put it in separate file import it, actually I have a util file that formats it...